# Locating CLI error logs when deploying an ASP.NET MVC5 app using web deploy fails

Tags: webdeploy

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC5 web app (web deploy deployment package) on my Windows Server using Command Prompt as I have done countless of times before with the same web app. When I try running the command

`myproject.deploy.cmd /t`

inside the correct folder the process starts but then abruptly stops and the CLI window closes.
Just before the window disappears I can see an error message in red, but I just do not have enough time to read what it says.

My question is where does one find the logs for commands that have failed? Alternatively is there a way to force the CLI to stay open in order to read the error displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the logs in the Event Viewer:

Event Viewer -> Applications and Services -> Microsoft -> Windows -> WebDeploy -> Errors